# access MAT via pointer in opencv android JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I have following jni method in which I pass file address of image.

```
public native long readMat(String imagePath);
```

inside this method I am reading MAT from given address with this

```
const char *realPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(imagePath, 0);
Mat host= imread(realPath);
```

now suppose I have some other java methods which does some operation on this mat,
and I want to access this MAT in those  methods too, but I dont want to read it again and again, so I am trying to figure out any way that that can help me keeping a reference of MAT and use it every time whenever I want to perform any operation on it.

Comment: Create a class with `Mat` data members and pass object of that class to `readMat` function.

Comment: @Zindarod I an trying to avoid calling Mat in java.